# swift enum is ignoring CodingKeys

Tags: swift, enums, codable, decodable

I have a some nested swift classes that are automatically decoded from `JSON` using the `Decodable` protocol. Everything works except this one enum.

The json data is a capitalised string of either `Open` or `Fulfilled`.

If I use this enum, everything decodes perfectly fine:

```
enum Status: String, Codable {
    case Open, Fulfilled
}
```

however i'm trying to get the cases to not use capitalized like this:

```
enum Status: String, Codable {
    
    case open, fulfilled
    
    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case open       = "Open"
        case fulfilled  = "Fulfilled"
    }
}
```

This gives me a decoding error saying:

> debugDescription: "Cannot initialize Status from invalid String value Open"

Do `CodingKeys` not work like this for enums?

Comment: `Do CodingKeys not work like this for enums?` Joakim covers what to do here, but to answer this: there is a default `Codable` implementation for things which are `RawRepresentable` by each of the "base" `Codable` types (`String`, `Int`, `Bool`, etc.). [The one for `String`](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/1e49c3bfeab3768a94ffb8a553ae51901d80d4af/stdlib/public/core/Codable.swift#L4577) encodes the raw value directly, and `CodingKeys` are not involved at all — because you get this default implementation, your `CodingKeys` enum has no influence over the effective behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the raw value type of your enum is `String` you can assign the correct strings directly to your enum items

```
enum Status: String, Codable {
    case open = "Open"
    case fulfilled = "Fulfilled"
}
```

If you for some reason do not want to do it this way then you need to implement a custom `init(from:)`

```
enum Status: String, Codable {
    case open, fulfilled

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.singleValueContainer()
        let value = try container.decode(String.self)
        switch value {
        case "Open":
            self = .open
        case "Fulfilled":
            self = .fulfilled
        default:
            // throw an error or use fatalError()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow, I never thought to directly assign them  thanks